# How can I share data between routes on the request object in Express?

Tags: express, spotify, passport.js

I'm working on an application that authenticates with Spotify's API. I am using [passport-spotify](https://github.com/JMPerez/passport-spotify) to do so. I need to be able to access a session ID a my root route (`/`).

While I'm able to set the session id during the `/callback` after authentication with Spotify, I can't then access the session id at `/`. Can someone please explain to me how to pass data between routes in Express so that I can access `req.session.id` in `/` after I've authenticated?

I'll share my endpoints here:

**`/`**

```
app.get('/', cors(), (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.id != null) {
  res.json({isAuthenticated: true })
} else {
  res.json({isAuthenticated: false, message: 'Please log in.' })
}
```

})

**Passport Strategy**

```
passport.use(new SpotifyStrategy({
  clientID: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret,
  callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL
},
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
     process.nextTick(function () {
       let user = { spotifyId: profile.id, access_token: accessToken, 
         refresh_token: refreshToken }
       return done(null, user)
    })
  }))
```

**`/auth/spotify`**

```
app.get('/auth/spotify',
  passport.authenticate('spotify', {scope: ['user-read-email', 'user-
    read-private'], showDialog: true}),
  (req, res) => {
})
```

**`/callback`**

```
app.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('spotify', { 
  failureRedirect: '/', successRedirect: FRONTEND_URL }), (req, res, 
  next) => {
  req.session.id = req.user.spotifyId
  localStorage.setItem('access_token_' + req.session.id, 
  req.user.access_token)
  localStorage.setItem('refresh_token_' + req.session.id, 
  req.user.refresh_token)
  return next(null, req.session.id)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to share data in the way you asked your question, and the reason thereof is very simple, they are 2 different `req` Objects.

The what you can do, is define a separate middlware function, something like this :

```
function middlware(req, res, next) {
  req.session.id = req.user.spotifyId;
  next();
}
```

And you call that function in both of your routs as a middlware after the Spotify middlware.